# jQuery: Wrap only first and second child, not the rest of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, wrapall

In my actual code:

```html
<div id="mother">
  <div id="child-01"></div>
  <div id="child-02"></div>
  <div id="child-03"></div>
  </ul>
```

I need to produce:

```html
<div id="mother">
  <div id="myWrap">
    <div id="child-01"></div>
    <div id="child-02"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child-03"></div>
  </ul>
```

I was playing with wrap, .`wrapAll()` and children, but I'm stuck.

If in my actual code i have:

```html
<div id="mother">
  <div id="child-01"></div>
  <div id="child-02"></div>
  <div id="child-03"></div>
  </ul>

  <div id="uncle">
    <div id="cousin-01"></div>
    <div id="cousin-02"></div>
    <div id="cousin-03"></div>
    </ul>
```

How do i produce:

```html
<div id="mother">
  <div id="myWrap">
    <div id="child-01"></div>
    <div id="child-02"></div>
    <div id="cousin-02"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child-03"></div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove # from your HTML ids.

```
$("#mother div:eq(0), #mother div:eq(1)").wrapAll("<div id='father'></div>")
```

Answer (score 8):

First as [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284685/adam) said remove the `#` prefix from your id attributes.  Also match your closing tags, currently you have a `</ul>` where a `</div>` should be.

Then, you can do it using [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) like this:

```
$("#mother div:lt(2)").wrapAll("<div id='myWrap'></div>");
```

This gets everything less than index 2 (0 and 1 are the first 2), then wraps it.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9ht4W/).

Answer (score 1):

sharp should not be part of the id's.  Then you can do:

```
$('#child-01, #child-02').wrapAll('<div id="#mywrap" />');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".new-grid__item:nth-child(1), .new-grid__item:nth-child(2)").wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Please format your code and add some text stating why this answers the question