# CSS on hover for nested lists

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I have nested lists where I would like to show an icon when the mouse is over a certain li. Unfortunately, since the lists are nested, if I hover over any sub li, also the parent li gets the hover effect. I would like to ONLY have the hover effect for the LI the mouse is over and not for its parents.

```js
$(".cl-tmp-tsk").append('<span class="cw-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></span>');
```

```css
.cw-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 75%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.cl-tmp-tsk:hover > .cw-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="checklistTree" class="p-l-15">
  <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
    <label for="chk_0"><b>aaa</b>
      <br/>bbb</label>

    <ul>

      <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
        <label for="chk_0_0"><b>ccc</b>
          <br/>ddd</label>

      </li>

      <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
        <label for="chk_0_1"><b>eee</b>
          <br/>fff</label>

        <ul>

          <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
            <label for="chk_0_1_0"><b>ggg</b>
              <br/>hhh</label>

          </li>

          <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
            <label for="chk_0_1_1"><b>iii</b>
              <br/>jjj</label>

            <ul>

              <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                <label for="chk_0_1_1_0"><b>kkk</b>
                  <br/>sss</label>

                <ul>

                  <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1_0_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                    <label for="chk_0_1_1_0_0"><b>qqq</b>
                      <br/>ppp</label>
                  </li>

                </ul>


            </ul>

            </li>

            <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
              <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_2" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
              <label for="chk_0_1_2"><b>111</b>
                <br/>fff</label>

            </li>

        </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_2" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
          <label for="chk_0_2"><b>222</b>
            <br/>
          </label>

        </li>

    </ul>

    </li>


    <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
      <label for="chk_1"><b>333</b>
        <br/>
      </label>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Changes to the html structure should be avoided as the provided code is part of a more complex page. Also, I need to be able to have 'on click' event for the cw-icon class as in production it will be a button.

Comment: Seems to me like a question that would have been asked many times before. Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990054/how-to-hover-only-current-li-in-nested-ul

Comment: Thanks but that is a JS solution not CSS

Comment: Ok, to answer that bit, there is no way to stop hover propagation in CSS. Or to select parent elements for that matter. So there's no way to do this in CSS only.

Comment: Also, the JS code provided is very shaky. It causes flickering as you move your mouse over the whole list.

Comment: E.g. when you try to click on the icon it disappears as it "out" of the LI. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzwdLW

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure css solution, you can wrap the content of each `li` in a `<div>` or `<span>` or another wrapping element and target that. see below.

```js
$(".icon-wrap").append('<span class="cw-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></span>');
```

```css
.cw-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 75%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.icon-wrap:hover > .cw-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="checklistTree" class="p-l-15">
  <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
    <div class="icon-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
      <label for="chk_0"><b>aaa</b>
        <br/>bbb</label>
      </div>
      <ul>
        
        <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
          <div class="icon-wrap">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
            <label for="chk_0_0"><b>ccc</b>
              <br/>ddd</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
            <div class="icon-wrap">
              <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
              <label for="chk_0_1"><b>eee</b>
                <br/>fff</label>
              </div>
              <ul>
                
                <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                  <div class="icon-wrap">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                    <label for="chk_0_1_0"><b>ggg</b>
                      <br/>hhh</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                    <div class="icon-wrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                      <label for="chk_0_1_1"><b>iii</b>
                        <br/>jjj</label>
                      </div>
                      
                      <ul>
                        
                        <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                          <div class="icon-wrap">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                            <label for="chk_0_1_1_0"><b>kkk</b>
                              <br/>sss</label>
                            </div>
                            
                            <ul>
                              
                              <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                                <div class="icon-wrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_1_0_0" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                                  <label for="chk_0_1_1_0_0"><b>qqq</b>
                                    <br/>ppp</label>
                                  </div>
                                </li>
                                
                              </ul>
                              
                              
                            </ul>
                            
                          </li>
                          
                          <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                            <div class="icon-wrap">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_1_2" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                              <label for="chk_0_1_2"><b>111</b>
                                <br/>fff</label>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            
                          </ul>
                          
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                          <div class="icon-wrap">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_0_2" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                            <label for="chk_0_2"><b>222</b>
                              <br/>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        
                      </ul>
                      
                    </li>
                    
                    
                    <li class="checkbox cl-tmp-tsk">
                      <div class="icon-wrap">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" /><i class="input-helper"></i>
                        <label for="chk_1"><b>333</b>
                          <br/>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    
                  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a I can live with a JS solution but not html change which is bad for SEO.

Comment: Do you see a way to add the wrapping in Jquery so that the HTML stays the same for SEO?

Comment: First off, it's pretty well established that google will now execute most JS, so you can't count on being able change up your DOM and have it not impact the crawl. Secondly, I don't think there is much evidence that a wrapping span or div would change SEO dramatically. If you wanted to add the wrapper via JS you could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638122/jquery-wrap-only-first-and-second-child-not-the-rest-of-children

Comment: You could also change the `<label>` to wrap the checkbox and fill the `<li>` and target it for the hover